# Response.Redirect to a Clickonce not working if done during postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clickonce, postback

Very odd situation here. I'm trying to launch a .application file using Response.Redirect. In the Page_Load event, if I check that it is a postback, it doesn't launch (it does otherwise). If I redirect to another page in postback, it works fine.

The reason I'm launching in postback is I'm checking that .Net is installed by grabbing navigator.useragent in javascript and sending that back to asp.net via a postback (actually a form[0].submit()) to see if the .Net framework is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternate you could send the meta tag to the browser

You could also check the UserAgent without the postback by checking [HttpRequest.UserAgent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx) or Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").

Comment: I should have mentioned that the reason I'm posting the nagigator.useragent is because newer browsers (IE9, FF4) don't show the .Net CLR version any more in the methods you've mentioned.

How would I go about sending the meta tag to the browser?

Comment: You can just to Response.Write, or have a static page with that meta tag and redirect to that page.